# What is the best approach to have a typescript returning function that uses try catch?

Tags: ajax, typescript, types, try-catch

Hello dear developers. So I have a question regarding returning functions that use try-catch on typescript. I want to make an http request and then return the data. In case an error occurs I can either return an empty array or throw the error. The function below is then being called by another function that will process the data. What is the best approach for this. Having it like this is giving me an error regarding the returning type of getData()

```
    static getData = async (): Promise<number[]> => {
            let data: number[] = [];
            try {
                axios
                    .get(`endpoint/getData`)
                    .then((res) => {
                        data= res.data;
                        return data;
                    });
            } catch (error) {
                return data;
            }
        };
//Example 
    static getUnixTime = async(): number => {
          const data = this.getData();
          return data[0]/1000 ;

    }
```

Comment: `axios` -> `return axios` to actually return the response. `return await axios` to also make use of the `try/catch`

Comment: Can you please clarify how this would be implemented?

Comment: By adding the words `return` and `await` in front of the word `axios`.